# Marking a field invalid

Tags: forms, extjs

I use a custom AJAX vtype, which works and all.
However I notice the extjs docs note that

"Note: this method does not cause the Field's validate or isValid methods to return false if the value does pass validation. So simply marking a Field as invalid will not prevent submission of forms submitted with the Ext.form.action.Submit.clientValidation option set."

How does one mark a field as invalid so that form.isValid() returns false?
My vtype:

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes, {
username: function(value, field){        
    var conn = new Ext.data.Connection();
    conn.request({
        url: 'test.php',
        params:{email:value},
        method: 'POST',

        success: function(responseObject){
            var resp = responseObject.responseText;
            if (resp == 0) {
                field.markInvalid('This email is invalid or already registered!');                
            } else if (resp == 1) {
                field.clearInvalid();
            }
        },
        failure: function(){                
           Ext.Msg.show({title: 'Error', msg: 'Connection error!',});
        }
    });
    return true;
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you look at the definition of `clientValidation`:

> Determines whether a Form's fields are validated in a final call to
>   isValid prior to submission. Pass false in the Form's submit options
>   to prevent this. If not defined, pre-submission field validation is
>   performed.

This is basically saying, if its set to `false` then the form will be automatically validated prior to submission... at which point it will fail if you have marked any fields as invalid. If you set it to `true` then you need to manually check if the form is valid before submitting.

It's worth pointing out that your AJAX vtype is never going to work. When the form calls the vtype to check whether the field is valid, all it gets in response is `true`... so the form submits no matter what. Even if you tell it to return after the ajax request has completed, the form would submit before the vtype ajax request completes.

A better solution would be to include the call to the vtype manually in your submit button handler...then in your `success` of the ajax request just do

```
if(form.isValid()) {
   form.getForm().submit();
}
```

This will force the submit button's click event to first validate the username field and then, and only then, will it submit the form.

Comment: Submitting the form like that would break the asynchrony. :( I would prefer to avoid manual validation for the form, would theoritically be much easier to have a function that over rides the vtype checking, that sets isValid= false; somehow.

Comment: You can't, without tying into the ajax success call, because it is asynchronous by nature... the form validation returns true and the form is submitted before the ajax request ever completes. You will either have to override the `submit()` method, maybe force it to check all types and fire ajax requests manually, and also force it to take a callback function as an argument...